# Why does this code seem to execute after the return statement?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, game-physics

Background info: I'm making a really basic 2D platformer with HTML5 canvas.
Inside my main gameloop, I iterate over all the objects to check if the player is standing on an object. If so, I end the execution of the function until the next loop.

In case an object and the player are colliding, before using `return` to exit the function (since we know the player is standing on that object), I set the player's velocity on the Y axis to 0, adjust his Y position slightly just to align him and the object properly, and set the player's property: `player.grounded` to true. This is where the main problem lies. It is a required boolean value that ties with the `player.isFalling` property. An update function checks if the player's Y velocity is higher than 0 and checks if he isn't grounded. In that case `player.isFalling` is true. The standingCheck helper function only executes if `isFalling` is true.

```
const standingCheckHandler = (player) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++){
    if(standingCheck(player, objects[i])){
      player.pos.y = objects[i].pos.y - player.height;
      player.velocity.y = 0;
      player.grounded = true;
      return;
    }else{
      player.grounded = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Now for the problem: even though I exit the function, or use `break`, the loop still continues iterating over the other objects. I'll log `player.grounded` and even after it is set to `true` (which means the function should quit itself, right?), it will go on to loop over the other objects and sets `player.grounded` to `false`, which causes dodgy movement in the game itself. (In theory it works, but the player keeps on bobbing up and down slightly which isn't really a nice sight).

I've tried all kinds of things. Use new properties, count the amount of objects the player could stand on, nothing seems to work. I feel like I'm overlooking something, but I'm not sure as to what that might be.

*(sorry for the wall of text!)*

**Update:** this is the standingCheck method:

```
const standingCheck = (a, b) => {
  // a = player, b = object
  if(a.isFalling){
    if(!(a.pos.x > b.pos.x + b.width || a.pos.x + a.width < b.pos.x)){ //x
      if(a.pos.y + a.height < b.pos.y && a.pos.y + a.height >= b.pos.y){ //y
          return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: return false; ? and update i to be objects.length, i = objects.length.

Comment: return; is equal to return false

Comment: @Gatsbill It's actually equal to `return undefined;` Which then evaluates to false in a logical expression. ;)

Comment: @sven plz share `standingCheck` method as well, as problem may be in that method also

Comment: @jeshu, sure, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. Although it did not fix the bug directly, I managed to work around the problem by introducing a new helper function:
`groundedCheck` is much the same as `standingCheck`. It basically only checks if the player is effectively still grounded (if the player.y + player.height equals to an object.y).

There *<strike>might be</strike>* definitely is a faster way to do it, but this works for now.

**How I fixed it:**

```
const standingCheckHandler = (player) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < objects.length; i ++){
    if(standingCheck(player, objects[i])){
      player.pos.y = objects[i].pos.y - player.height;
      player.velocity.y = 0;
      player.grounded = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  // this is new
  if(player.grounded){
    let len = objects.length;
    for(let j = 0; j < objects.length; j ++){
      if(!groundedCheck(player, objects[j])){
        len --;
      }
    }
    if(len <= 0){
      player.grounded = false;
    }
  }
}

// so is this
const groundedCheck = (a, b) => {
  // a = player, b = object
  if(!(a.pos.x > b.pos.x + b.width || a.pos.x + a.width < b.pos.x)){
    if(a.pos.y + a.height === b.pos.y){
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```